# Why BotConnector behavior is different from the emulator?

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework, botconnector

I am playing with recently released Microsoft Bot Framework. 
I did the following steps:

1. Created a simple bot using IDialog ([Echo Bot sample](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html#simpleEcho)), tested with emulator, deployed to Azure App Service and registered it at dev.botframework.com. Everything worked fine.
2. Updated the bot to work with Luis using LuisDialog, and added [LuisModel] and [LuisIntent] attributes (basing on [Alarm Bot sample](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html#alarmBot)) and deployed it to the cloud.

After that I have a strange behavior:

Both local and cloud deployments work as expected using emulator, and Luis part works well.

When triggering the same bot from BotConnector test connection, it doesn't bind Luis, but enters MessageReceivedAsync instead.

I checked the bot path, app id and keys, redeployed AppService and re-registered the bot, and I still get the same behavior.

My ReceiveMessageAsync looks the following:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Message> result)
{
  var message = await result;

  await context.PostAsync("You have just said: " + message.Text);
  context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

The reason I don't delete it, is because the test connection stops working without it. Emulator, on the other hand, works well.

Aren't test connection in BotConnector and emulator pointing to the same endpoint expected to ALWAYS return same results?
Or, am I missing something?

Comment: The MessageReceivedAsync you mentioned -- is it _your_ MessageReceivedAsync, or is it LuisDialog.MessageReceivedAsync? The one in LuisDialog is always called, because that's the thing that dispatches to your Luis methods. If it's your own ... you need to remove it so the one in LuisDialog can handle and dispatch.

It should work the same way between the emulator and the Connector, but we can work on that after we know which method you're seeing called.

Comment: I updated the post with details. I can't delete this MessageReceivedAsync method from EchoBot sample because it breaks test connection. As well, when I redeploy with slightly modifying the string ("You said", "You have said", "You have just said") - I see these changes in test connection, but it still doesn't enter Luis part. And again, endpoint works correctly when I trigger it from emulator. I can share code/appid/secrets if needed.

Comment: I think the problem is that your Luis dialog is broken in some way. Adding your own MessageReceivedAsync is hiding the failure on your dev machine, but when you deploy, that hiding isn't working (either because you're deploying Release bits, or because IIS is working differently from IIS Express, or something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not applicable anymore. Newer 1.1 version, which BTW introduced breaking changes, works like a charm on the same codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Bot Connector and the emulator send the same messages.

Whether your code returns the same value depends on how you deal with the message, the calling environment (called from localhost over HTTP instead of remotely over HTTPS), and the hosting environment (typically debug bits in IIS Express vs. release bits in IIS, for C# applications).